# Does a thicker wire mean more charge carriers in I = n A q V?

Tags: circuit-analysis

If you have two wires A & B made of same material with A being twice as thick as B, when using the formula I = n A q V will the value of n and Q remain the same for both wires or will they change?

I think because the A wire is more thick it therefore has more valence electrons that can carry charge and therefore the number of charge carriers should increase compared to wire B. But i think i heard someone say that n & q remains constant and only A & V value changes.

Answer (score 5):

N and Q do not change. N is the number of free electrons per unit volume. This is an intrinsic property of the material, not it's dimensions. Q is always -1.6*10^-19 for electrons. Thus the only thing that changes for a "Thicker" wire is the cross-sectional area, A.

Comment: So does that mean that every material has it's charge carriers set per m^3? And the only way you can change the value of n is by changing the material of the wire itself?

Comment: @jyashi, That is correct. n is a property of the material and is "locked" for most materials.

Comment: *N* will vary with temperature. It will vary pretty strongly in semiconductors, less in metals and insulators.

Comment: @ThePhoton, When he knows to ask that question then you should tell him the answer. n is "locked" for most of the questions where you use this, and for the few where it's not it will give you the temperature relation. After all, there are Meta Materials where N varies by things like magnetic field and such. But jyashi's not covering those yet. (Mostly I didn't want to over load him with *everything*)